# How to Create a Folder in Project using Custom IWizard in VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, wizard, project-template

i am creating a custom wizard, i want to create a folder inside my project and add some files into this folder. i used this codes

```
Project project = _dte.Solution.Projects.Item(1);
project.ProjectItems.AddFolder("Common");
```

but i get a null refrence exception.

can someone tell me how i can create a folder for my project?

Comment: I have done it in the template (you just create the folder structure you want ahead, when you prepare the template). Is there a reason you are trying to do it programmatically? Also, which object is null?

Comment: @Nikolay i dont know which object is null vs is show a wizard.cs file which is built in class, also i fixed issue with AddToDirectory

Comment: You can use debugger, lol.  Meaning, you can debug one instance of Visual Studio from another. Including stepping through your wizard in debugger.